# Continually add items from a segue to an array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I currently have an array of arrays of "People", who have names and addresses. It looks like this:

```
let c1 = Person(name:"Bob Smith",address:"100 Main Street")
let c2 = Person(name:"Add Person...",address:"")
var pDirec = [[c1],[c2]]
```

When the "Add Person..." cell is tapped in my table view, it sends the user to another view where they can give a person a name/address and submit, so that the data is passed back to the original view.  I just don't have any idea how to add that new person object to the existing array, in the first section. So for example if you passed a person "c3" back, the array would look like:

```
pDirec = [[c1,c3],[c2]]
```

And you would be able to add more and more people in this fashion.

Comment: I don't understand why if it's an array of `[Person]` do you have `[[c1],[c2]]`, can you explain more please?

Comment: Sorry, it's an array of arrays of [Person], I will update the question.

Comment: When the data is passed back, get the array at index 0 of `pDirec` and add the `Person` item. However if `Person` is a `struct` rather than a `class` you have to write the array back to index 0 of `pDirec` due to the value semantics of structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the array you've created is currently adding arrays of 1 person into your array. You might want to change that to:

`var pDirec = [c1, c2] as? NSMutableArray`

After that, you can add objects to that array with:

`pDirec.addObject(newPersonObject)`

The above should result in an array that looks like:

`[c1, c2, c3]`

Answer (score 0):

`pDirec.first?.append(c3)`
or
`pDirec[0]?.append(c3)`

Will append `c3` to the first array in the pDirec multi-dimensional array.  We use the `?` in case you haven't started the array yet, so it won't crash on trying to add.